# How to update buffer?

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi, cluster-computing, ipc, distributed-computing

I would like to know:

If a make two consecutive MPI_Isend requests, and if the destination processor has not yet receive the message inbetween the two calls, will the buffer be updated ?
I mean if I send message "0" for the first request, then send "1" as the second message. Will the receiver receive "0" as message ? I not, how can I do to update the message ?

Thanks

```
double message;
int i = 0;
 //First processor
 if (rank == 0) 
    {

        for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            message = i;
            MPI_Isend(&message, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, 1, 0, PETSC_COMM_WORLD, r_send);
            
        }

    }


    //Second processor
    if (rank == 1) 
    {
            PetscSleep(10); // Make this processor sleep for 10 seconds
            int flag = 0;
            MPI_Irecv(&message, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, 0, PETSC_COMM_WORLD, r_recv);
            MPI_Test(r_recv,&flag, r_status);
            while (!flag)
            {
                MPI_Test(r_recv,&flag, r_status);
            }
            printf("the message is %lf\n",message);


    }
```

This code above will print "the message is 0". I want it to take into account the last update, not the first in-order messages.

Comment: Question is unclear. Can you write a couple of lines of code to illustrate your question?

Comment: Just edited the post

Comment: This program is incorrect w.r.t. the MPI standard since the send buffer (`message`) might be overwritten before being sent. TL;DR do not overwrite the send buffer before you `MPI_Wait()` the request.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

1. MPI messages are "non-overtaking", meaning that the first message sent will be received first. So when you post your `Irecv`, that first message will be received. 2. I don't think the tests after the receive do anything useful. If your test says there is a message, you need a new receive to get it. 3. Why are you using a "ready" send? 4. Neither of your processes is doing a `Wait` call, so it could be that this whole program is Undefined Behavior.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answer. For answers 2 to 3, it was bad editing. I badly edited the code before posting. For answer 4, i didn't use Wait because I didn't want a blocking communication. This program above, print "the message is 0" before stopping

Comment: An indirect communication without wait is undefined. You can use `MPI_Iprobe` to make the receive non-blocking. The send without wait is a memory leak.